# How can I stop this page titles being marked as duplicate?

Tags: seo, title-attribute

We have a directory of the most influential people in a sector.
People can appear in more than one year, with different citation

The page title tag is generated dynamically and would change like this
John Doe, Power 50 Profile 2013 
John Doe, Power 50 Profile 2014 
John Doe, Power 50 Profile 2015

In webmaster tools, these pages are coming up as having duplicate titles. Is the year not enough to mark them as different?
What more can I do, while keeping the process dynamic?

Comment: Is yours website prepared in word-press?

Comment: if, yes so click on the mentioned link to fix this problem.   http://www.searchenginenow.com/how-to/fix-duplicate-title-tags-google-webmaster-tools-paginated-posts/

Comment: No it is not in Wordpress. But thanks for the comment

Comment: This is just a notice. All titles should be relative unique. Adding the year may not be helpful to your users to distinguish one page from the next. If you can mix it up more in a way that makes sense for your users that would be better. Otherwise, I would not worry about this too much as long as the title works well as a SERP link. Mother Superior Google will not paddle you in front of the class for this. It is just a warning/notice for your benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and thanks for making me smile :)

Answer (score 1):

Google scans every URL that you submit to them in a Sitemap. It also scans URLs linked to the ones you submitted, and it may even scan all URLs linked to the home page.

You will definitely need to visit the HTML improvements section in Google Webmaster Tools for the website that supposedly has duplicate page titles and take note of all the URLs presented. Google is very accurate when it identifies URLs with duplicate titles.

If you have backups of the affected pages that are live, then that's the problem, because a backup copy is generally the same as a good copy.

For example, if you receive URLs grouped like the following (after expanding each duplicate title):

```
http://example.com/power50profile2015/backup
http://example.com/power50profile2015

http://example.com/power50profile2014/backup
http://example.com/power50profile2014

http://example.com/power50profile2013/backup
http://example.com/power50profile2013
```

Then its a clear indication that you have made a backup copy of your work, but you need to make one version unavailable to the public either by placing it outside of the document root folder or changing permissions on the affected version so that the outside world has no access.

If after you done all that, you still notice problems, then I would give Google one to two weeks for it to process your site because Google is slow at updating some things. Another thing you can do to speed up Google's processing time is to select the gear icon in Google Webmaster Tools, and select site settings, and change Google's crawl rate and move the slider all the way to the right.